# Debug popup.html of a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome Extension and need to view the HTML/CSS/JS of the `popup.html`.

I can't right click to inspect elements. Is there another way? I need to make sure CSS and JavaScript is being inserted correctly. How to debug a problem in that popup file?

Comment: Documentation for the records, Tutorial: Debugging: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Right click the extension's button, then 'Inspect Popup'

Comment: In Chrome 22 (Canary on 8/1/2012), the 'Inspect Popup' option has been removed, probably because you can 'Inspect Element' from within the popup. However, because of this, there is no way to debug/set a breakpoint on code that runs on load. So far my only solution is to put a setTimeout for 10-15 seconds, which allows me time to open the popup, select 'Inspect Element', find the Scripts tag and set the breakpoint inside the timed-out function. Do you know of an easier way?

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I wish the chrome team would stop breaking things.

Comment: inspect the popup windows itself and then use location.reload(true) to relead it

Comment: `Inspect popup` is verified present in version 38, possibly in earlier versions as well.

Comment: This seems outdated. Please consider @Tom N's reply below.

Comment: It works but there is anyway to bring the console into the front of the webpage or docking it inside the current webpage? @TimCodes.NET

Answer (score 105):

Inspect Popup has gone away with the latest build.

Here's how I debug Chrome Extension Popups.

1. Click your popup button to see the webpage (the popup window itself).
2. Right-click in the window and select Inspect element
3. The Chrome Debugger window comes up with the right context, but you've already missed your breakpoints and `debugger` statements.
4. HERE'S THE TRICK. Click on the Console part of the debugger and type: `location.reload(true)` and press enter.

Now your breakpoints are hit! Great way to reload changed scripts without revisiting the Extension page.

Comment: I do get the popup when I rightcilck on the page action icon.

Comment: You can also just hit F5 while in the debugger, it triggers "reload" not "run". Though this should be considered as UI bug, since developers would expect F5 to "run", not "reload". So, beware of this helpful F5 has messed up some debuggings of mine too when hit at the wrong time. The latter also happens in Firefox.

Comment: In Chrome 47 not hitting breakpoints on extension load is still a problem, so your location.reload(true) tip is priceless!

Comment: This is a great workaround. Very often "Inspect Popup" will not hit breakpoints.

Answer (score 40):

Perhaps another way may be to find the ID: for your application in chrome://chrome/extensions/

You can then load your popup in a regular window by

```
chrome-extension://id_of_your_application/popup.html
```

Exchange popup.html for the file you have specified in manifest.json under "default_popup" property.

Comment: I tried it and it works if your extension is a popup. Here is an example of AdBlock popup link that runs in the browser. You must have AdBlock installed. chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/button/popup.html

Comment: This is especially nice because Chrome reloads the popup page every time you click the toolbar button, and the "Inspect Popup" console is automatically closed whenever the popup is blurred.

Comment: Some extensions do not have popup.html. You have to know the file's name before debugging.

Comment: Sweet! This and [Tom N answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039875/chrome-extension-debug-popup-html/12068406#12068406) are priceless. Accepted answer is not the best, at all.

Comment: THANK YOU @PavelHlobil !

Comment: This totally gets around the issue of not being able to see initial requests in DevTools when the extension is first opened. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 'Inspect Popup' on the extension icon, and apart from that - from extension manager you can also inspect your options page.

Answer (score 2):

Try switching **Auto-open DevTools for popups** in the bottom right of DevTools **Settings**:

[image: Auto-open DevTools]

Another good way to inspect Javascript being part of the extension popup is adding special comments to the end of the script to be debugged:

```
// @sourceURL=popup.js
```

This is de-facto a *directive* for **DevTools** to include this specific file into **Sources** tab. From there you can inspect code, add breakpoints, output to console, etc. as usual.